# How i can get the path of svg file via RestApi Angular js

Tags: rest, svg

I retrieve data via Rest Api, the data is: Svg file name, path to svg file, and svg file id. how can I recover the path to the files to display it correctly in a widget with angular js.
Id_Leaf IS the id of filesvg
Path_Leaf contains all the informations (id,nameN path)
 i have this code :

```
$scope.LoadLeaf = function (Id_Leaf) {
    RESTSummoner.DoGET(PATH_LEAF, "/" + Id_Leaf).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Leaf = data;
        console.log($scope.Leaf);
    }).error(function () {

    });
}
```